# Wordpress with CAS+LDAP and standard WP accounts

Tags: plugins, login, remote-login

I have a wordpress site setup with the [wpCAS-w-LDAP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpcas-w-ldap/) for logins. It's working perfectly except for one thing. We have some users who can't login using the CAS system since they don't have an account there (outside our control). Therefore we want to enable some kind of system where the user first is prompted if he/she want to login using CAS or with a standard wordpress account.

Do you know of any plugins like this?

Comment: Close voted as off-topic as the plugin hasn't been updated since more than two years and I've never seen any question about it before (or even heard about that service).

Answer (score 3):

I've made WP Cassify, a Wordpress CAS Authentication plugin which 's compatible with the last CAS version. It's hosted on the Official Wordpress Plugins Directory :https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cassify/

I've made screencast 'BYPASS CAS AUTHENTICATION' which explain you how to set up both authentications types on the same page (CAS Auth + Classic Wordpress Auth) :
https://wpcassify.wordpress.com/getting-started/

Best regards